# UIRefreshControl issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to implement the `UIRefreshControl` in my application.  I have an xib file and I added a `UITableViewController` to the empty nib file and I set the refresh property to "enabled".  Also I have added code to the `viewDidLoad` and a custom refresh method.  The problem is I have an error I can't find any information on....in my `viewDidLoad` I get "Property '`refreshControl`' not found on object of type `ViewController`"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.myTableView =
[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                           style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

self.myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];

UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.refreshControl = refresh;

}

-(void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing data..."];

// custom refresh logic would be placed here...

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
NSString *lastUpdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated on %@",
                                [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastUpdated];
[refresh endRefreshing];

}
```

I have no idea why that property isn't available....what am I missing?

Looks like I need to inherit from `UITableViewController` in my `ViewController.h` file.  If I already have `UITableView` there how do I inherit from both?  If I change my code from `ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` to  `ViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` then I get an error:

```
    error: NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
    reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "ViewController_iPhone" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `UIRefreshControl` as a subview to your `UITableView`.

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

As per Dave's comment, this may break in future version of iOS. So please be careful while using this and try to raise a [bug report to apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/) regarding this.

**Update:**
A better approach is by adding `UITableViewController` as a `ChildViewController` of `self` and then adding `tableViewController.tableView` as the subview of `self.view`. You dont have to do any hack to make it work in this way.

```
[self addChildViewController:tableViewController];
[self.view addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];
```

You can define the frame for `tableView` accordingly. Using this approach, `UIRefreshControl` should work in the same way as it works for `UITableViewController`.
`

Comment: This is unsupported and may break in future version of iOS. The only supported way to use a `UIRefreshControl` is with a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: @ACB, that is exactly what I needed!!!  Thanks a millions.  I wish I could give you more props!

Comment: Yes, you can have a UIRefreshControl on an UIViewController class with an UITableView and <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> that you added manually. The comments other answers may be true (it does not goes with the docs), but this little hack works on iOS6.

Comment: @akaru [The `UIRefreshControl` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) say: "You link a refresh control to a table through an associated table view controller object."  Thus, other methods of adding a `UIRefreshControl` to a `UITableView` are unsupported.

Comment: You should be using the `UITableViewController.refreshControl` property as per Narendra Pathai's answer.  Manually adding it to the `UITableView` like this is dangerous and could break in future versions of iOS.

Answer (score 5):

Things to Remember:

- `UIRefreshControl` only for `UITableViewController`, so your class should be the subclass of `UITableViewController`.
- `UITableViewController` has a property `refreshControl`, you should allocate a `UIRefreshControl`
  and set it to that property.

Ex:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Manually adding it to the `UITableView` as per the accepted answer could cause unexpected behaviour in future versions of iOS.

Answer (score 3):

All of these are complex ways of doing something simple.

You don't need to add a refresh control, or declare one in your viewController.  Adding pull-to-refresh is a two-step process.
Step 1: In your storyboard, go to your tableViewController and, where it says "Refreshing", select "Enabled".
Step 2: Add the following code to your tableViewController.m file, in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(refresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

That's the entire process, other than doing stuff in your -refresh method.  When you want it to stop refreshing, call `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];`.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling all the tutorials I was reading were overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ViewController` class must be a subclass of `UITableViewController` in order to have access to the `refreshControl` property.

Comment: We can add `UITableViewController` as a child view controller and then add `tableview` as a subview of `self.view` of current view controller, right? I was just wondering whether we really need to subclass?

Comment: @ACB Yes, you can use a `UITableViewController` as a child view controller.  That is an excellent approach.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was confused with this statement in your answer ***"ViewController class must be a subclass of UITableViewController"*** since we can add it as a subview as well.

Comment: @ACB that statement is meant to be interpreted in the context of the question above. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make separate UITableViewController Subclass for myTableView.
And then by using addChildviewController or iOS6 ContainerView to add that class within original ViewController. That way even in the part of View, you can use UIRefreshControl.

Accepted answer is not official way, so it could break in future release as comment said...